# Include models in Cakephp without going through index.php

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP to build a site which has a crawler that mines data from different sites. The problem is that I would like to be able to call the crawler from command line (since it can take hours for it to finnish) and I would like to the use models in CakePHP when saving the data.

Is there a file I could just include that includes the rest for me?
If I just include the index.php it dispatches the call which I don't want.

Regards Nicklas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Cake shell:
http://book.cakephp.org/view/108/The-CakePHP-Console

Comment: Brilliant, just what I needed :)